# How to record sqlplus session activity like "/var/messages" in Unix..?

Tags: oracle

something like

```
$ sqlplus '/as sysdba' @spool log1.txt
SQL>
```

--Is there anything like the above..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "like /var/messages". If you want to spool the output of a query you could use spool, or you could record the output from sqlplus (stdout/stderr) with redirection (e.g. > /file.txt 2>&1).

Answer (score 1):

Try `$ sqlplus / as sysdba | tee sqlplus.log`